# Update GridControl doesn't show changes when calling from other usercontrol

Tags: c#

I've created a method to update my GridControl. For my other GridControl I use the same method/constructor structure and I call it in the same way and it works. When I click the button which is in the same class as the update method the data in the grid is updated.But when I call this method (updateGridControl) from another usercontrol nothing happens to the GridControl. How to change my code that the method also updates the grid when I call it from another usercontrol/class?

This the call to the method:

```
incidentCategorySearchControl.Instance.updateGridControl(); // update doesn't work
```

incidentCategorySearchControl.cs

```
 public partial class incidentCategorySearchControl : UserControl
{
    public static incidentCategorySearchControl Instance { get; set; }


    public incidentCategorySearchControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;

        // This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
        incIncidentCategoryTableAdapter1.Fill(reinvenT_QualityDataSet1.IncIncidentCategory);

        bindingSource1.DataSource = reinvenT_QualityDataSet1;
    }

    public void updateGridControl()
    {
        incIncidentCategoryTableAdapter1.Fill(reinvenT_QualityDataSet1.IncIncidentCategory);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// GridControl row doubleclick handling 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="view"></param>
    /// <param name="pt"></param>

    public void DoRowDoubleClick(GridView view, Point pt)
    {

        GridHitInfo info = view.CalcHitInfo(pt);

        if (info.InRow || info.InRowCell)
        {
            try
            {
                string colCaption = info.Column == null ? "N/A" : info.Column.GetCaption();
                Form1 myform = (Form1)this.categoryGridControl.FindForm();
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(view.GetRowCellValue(info.RowHandle, "IncIncidentCategory"));
                string description=view.GetRowCellValue(info.RowHandle,"IncIncidentCatDescription").ToString();

                IncidentCategory incidentCategoryEditTarget = new IncidentCategory(id, description);
                incidentCategoryChange.Instance.TextBoxCategory = incidentCategoryEditTarget._categoryId.ToString();
                incidentCategoryChange.Instance.TextBoxCategoryDesc = incidentCategoryEditTarget._description;

                XtraTabPage xtraTabPage = myform.xtraTabControl1.TabPages[3];
                xtraTabPage.PageVisible = true;
                myform.xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage = xtraTabPage;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// CategoryGridControl double click event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>

    private void categoryGridControl_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = (GridView)categoryGridControl.MainView;

        Point pt = view.GridControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);

        DoRowDoubleClick(view, pt);
    }


    private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 myform = (Form1)this.closeButton.FindForm();
        myform.xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage.PageVisible = false;
    }

    private void addCategoryButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 myform = (Form1)this.addCategoryButton.FindForm();
        XtraTabPage xtraTabPage = myform.xtraTabControl1.TabPages[2];
        xtraTabPage.PageVisible = true;
        myform.xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage = xtraTabPage;
    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateGridControl();
    }            
}
```

incidentCategoryChange.cs

```
namespace REINVENT.Quality
{
    public partial class incidentCategoryChange : UserControl
    {
        public static incidentCategoryChange Instance { get; set; }
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        public incidentCategoryChange()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Instance = this;

            // set no blinking
            errorProvider1.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink;
        }

        //public property get/set incidentcategory 

        public string TextBoxCategory
        {
            get { return incidentCategoryTextBox.Text; }
            set { incidentCategoryTextBox.Text = value; }
        }

        //public property get/set incidentcategory description

        public string TextBoxCategoryDesc
        {
            get { return incidentCategoryDescTextBox.Text; }
            set { incidentCategoryDescTextBox.Text = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if a control contains text
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="control"><Control</param>

        public void controlContainsText(Control control)
        {
            string errorMessage = "Dit veld mag niet leeg zijn";
            if (control.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
                errorProvider1.SetError(control, errorMessage);
            else
                errorProvider1.SetError(control, "");
        }

        private void closeCategoryChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 myform = (Form1)this.closeCategoryChangeButton.FindForm();
            incidentCategoryDescTextBox.Enabled = true;
            myform.xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage.PageVisible = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save the category to the database if the required fields are filled and update grids
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">sender object</param>
        /// <param name="e">event</param>

        private void saveCategoryChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (incidentCategoryDescTextBox.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Opslaan mislukt controleer a.u.b. of alle verplichte velden juist zijn ingevuld");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlServerConnection.sqlConnection.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE IncIncidentCategory SET IncIncidentCatDescription = @categoryDescription WHERE IncIncidentCategory = @categoryId", con))
                        {
                            IncidentCategory incidentCategoryUpdate = new IncidentCategory(Convert.ToInt32(incidentCategoryTextBox.Text), incidentCategoryDescTextBox.Text);
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryId", incidentCategoryUpdate._categoryId);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryDescription", incidentCategoryUpdate._description);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MessageBox.Show("Wijzigingen opgeslagen"); 

                        }
                    }

                    incidentTypeChange.Instance.refreshCategorySearchBox();
                    incidentTypeMaintenance.Instance.refreshCategorySearchBox();
                    incidentCategorySearchControl.Instance.updateGridControl(); // update doesn't work 




                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Voer voor beide velden geldige waarden in a.u.b.");
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Delete a category after confirmation of the user and update grids.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sender</param>
        /// <param name="e">event</param>

        private void deleteCategoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Weet u zeker dat u deze categorie wilt verwijderen?", "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                try
                {

                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SqlServerConnection.sqlConnection.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM IncIncidentCategory WHERE IncIncidentCategory = @idDelete", con))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idDelete", Convert.ToInt32(incidentCategoryTextBox.Text));
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                incidentCategoryTextBox.Text = "";
                incidentCategoryDescTextBox.Text = "";
                MessageBox.Show("De categorie is verwijderd");
                incidentTypeChange.Instance.refreshCategorySearchBox();
                incidentTypeMaintenance.Instance.refreshCategorySearchBox();



                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Voer voor beide velden geldige waarden in a.u.b. Verwijzingen naar deze catergorie dienen eerst verwijderd/aangepast te worden");
                }         


            }
        }

        private void incidentCategoryDescTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
           controlContainsText(incidentCategoryDescTextBox);
        }

        private void newCategoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 myform = (Form1)this.newCategoryButton.FindForm();
            XtraTabPage xtraTabPage = myform.xtraTabControl1.TabPages[2];
            xtraTabPage.PageVisible = true;
            myform.xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage = xtraTabPage;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: What means `"update doesn't work"`? Is it happening (set breakpoint)? Do you get exception? Result is not expected? If you call `updateGridControl()` by other means, is result correct? How do you conclude that `"Update GridControl doesn't show changes when calling from other usercontrol"`?

Comment: The line in the update method is reached when I run my program (I set a breakpoint on this line). I don't get any exceptions. The expected result that the GridControl shows the (newest) values which are in the database. When I press the simpleButton1 the method works a the GridControl is updated to the newest values from the database. But when I call the update method from my other usercontrol the values aren't updated

Comment: Your approach should work unless you are using **multiple** `incidentCategorySearchControl`s.

Comment: @Sinatr thanks alot that was the problem, another one was still hiding on my form, problem solved.